# Converting an item from a value within a controller to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly, but I am trying to convert something was in a controller to a directive because I want to use it multiple times and just change a few values, so instead of making many huge object literals, I will have just one and just change the values passed in. I am trying to bind `chartConfig`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing this wrong?

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('percentageSquare', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            bgClass: '@',
            percentage: '@',
            chartConfig: '='
        },
        link: function(scope){
            var fontSize = 80;
            var percentage = scope.percentage || 0;
            scope.chartConfig = {
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        // Chart settings here
                    }
                }
            };
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/charts/PercentageChart.html'
    };
});
```

Here is the template that the directive is using (**PercentageChart.html**):

```
<div class="drop-shadow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <highchart config="chartConfig" class="{{bgClass||''}}" ng-show="true"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I am calling the directive:

```
<percentage-square bg-class="bg-orange" percentage="23"></percentage-square>
```

Now my `chartConfig` no longer binds to the directive like it used to when it was in a controller. What can be done to fix this?

## Edit

I have gotten a little further, this seems to work:

```
scope.$watch(scope.chartConfig, function(){
    scope.chartConfig = {
       // Chart Settings
    };
});
```

But it seems to load the chart twice, as I get two animations.

Comment: Is your intention to bind `chartConfig` to the parent scope? If so then you should call directive like `<percentage-square bg-class="bg-orange" percentage="23" chart-config="parentScopeConfig"></percentage-square>`. If not then remove the `chartConfig: '='` definition from your directive scope definition

Comment: I think I need to remove it, because I want to bind the template `chartConfig` to the one in the `link` and not the parent. But it doesn't load the config when I remove it, so I don't think it is working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I want to do is watch `chartConfig`. it must also be wrapped in a string in order for it to work properly. Using `scope.chartConfig` loaded the chart twice, while `'chartConfig'` loads the chart once and properly.

```
scope.$watch('chartConfig', function(){
    scope.chartConfig = {
       // Chart Settings
    };
});
```